# Nested VIEWS in database

Tags: sql, database, view

I am searching for some info on using nested VIEWS for a college project. So my questions are:

1. What problem can arise from using multi level nested VIEW?
2. What would be alternative to resolve this in case a scenario exists where VIEWS are implemented in nested format.

Thank you :)

I searched on internet as well as on stackoverflow but information is really limited. So I am looking for more thorough information or experiences what other people faced in case they encountered such an issue.

Comment: A view hides the underlying complexity. I.e. simplifies the usage, but can - when inadequately handled - introduce performance problems. (Which isn't unique for views alone.)

Comment: The alternative would be to re-write the final view definition to use the underlying base tables rather than the interim views

Comment: @jarlh In my experience, entry-level developers tend to misuse them all the time. They run heavy queries on them, something the views were not intended for, and then the end user complains the entire app crashes. I would refrain from using view as much as possible.